# Put UILabel text inside a tooltip-like UIImage

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, uilabel

I have been searching various ways to put text on an image. I tried things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497311/uiimageview-only-displays-when-i-call-initwithimage) already, but it shows label as separate object along with image.

I want that text is just on the image (something like transparent label with just its text visible, but I don't know how objective C does it).

This is because the image I am talking about is a custom tooltip, and the text is variable, so I can't statically put it there.

Comment: You can use textview and disable its userinteraction and set image in background of UITextView,it will work according to your requirement ,i think so.Try it.. :)

Comment: thanks! But I have a custom image (a thinking cloud, if you have seen it) that needs resizing as per the text. Also, text needs to wrapped properly. It involved more than what I initially estimated, so I put off the whole idea :-(

Comment: Check this link :
http://tirania.org/monomac//archive/2012/Jan.html