# UIImageView (created programmatically) is not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode5

I am trying to add an UIImageView programatically to my modal view controller and the image simply does not show up. I only see the white background. The rest is working fine as I'm able to load or dismiss the view. My code below:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0352.PNG"];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];


UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeleft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeleft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiperight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swiperight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];


UIBarButtonItem *dismiss_btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Start App" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(dismissModal:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:dismiss_btn, nil];
```

Comment: This should work ... Try to add a backgroundColor for the imageView to check if the problem in the image being displayed or in the position of the imageView

Comment: the imagename with all uppercase is correct?

Comment: In addition to @HaniIbrahim suggestion of background color, I'd also recommend some `NSLog` outputs throughout here, check `imageView.image` for null.

Comment: Thanks guys. staticVoidMan comment below actually addressed it. Thare was a typo as I used "init" and "initWithFrame" at the same time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to drop

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
```

because... well... `init] initWithFrame:` looks like a typo <strike>and the following is a better way to init a `UIImageView`:</strike>

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0352.PNG"]];
```

ref: [UIImageView only displays when I call initWithImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497311/uiimageview-only-displays-when-i-call-initwithimage)

Comment: This isn't better if the image view needs to be a different size than the image.

Comment: and the frame needs furthermore to be set. or how should the view know where to place it?

Comment: @visualication : we have `setFrame` for that. atleast i always just simply init and `setFrame` later

Comment: @rmaddy : answers are case specific. his code doesn't indicate that he is resetting the image later also, his gesture is on self.view not the `imageView`

Comment: @staticVoidMan My point was that the image have a size other than 100x100. Besides, the frame needs to be set anyway. There's nothing wrong with using `initWithFrame:` then calling `setImage:`.

Comment: @rmaddy : but yeah, you are right, incase the image is too big then it'll spoil the look. (well i always do a `setFrame` anyways, so i've never really had such an issue)

Answer (score 3):

One serious problem is this line:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
```

It needs to be:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
```

You had an extra call to `init`.

Also be sure the filename is really named `IMG_0352.PNG`. Case matters. Make sure it's not really `IMG_0352.png` or something similar.

And of course be sure you actually have such an image being packed into your app. Make sure it is listed under the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of the "Build Phases" for your target.

Answer (score 0):

The `imageView` is getting initialized twice. Try to remove one `init`

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
```

Also while adding the images to the image folder check if the image/ folder is added as a "create group" option in Xcode and not with "create folder reference".
Folder reference will just give a link or reference, so you cannot actually access the elements in the folder.