# Custom UITableViewCell imageview not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Ok so I trimmed my complex application into a simple bogged down version for everyone to understand. So first I download a zip file from a server, unzip it and place it in the cache directory folder. All that happens in the AppDelegate and unzips and stores the images just fine. Upon the tableviews veiwdidload method call, I call a function that looks for the image file inside of the iPhones cache directory folder. After a successful image file has been found, I take the file path of that image

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImage;
```

.m

```
NSString * photo;

NSString * photoType = @"6F0C437D-1BB2-482B-BF11-39BCAB668E4C";

photo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BANNERLOGO%@.png", photoType];


NSArray *cachesPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);


NSString * cacheDir = [cachesPaths objectAtIndex:0];

cacheDir = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1D2EA159-A312-4FB5-8FE5-B95879B242BB"];


NSString * photoPath = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:photo];

BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:photoPath];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Error!!");
}

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:photoPath];

[self.theImage setImage:image];
```

So here's my issue. I can't seem to figure out why the image I am grabbing is not showing up? Does anyone have any ideas why this might be? Weird thing is, when I set the color of the tableview cell, it turns grey as I expect it to.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {


        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    }

    //DoesNot
    cell.bannerImageView.image = self.theImage.image;


    //Shows up in cell
   cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.9f blue:0.9f alpha:1.0f];

    return (UITableViewCell *)cell;
}
```

Here's the code to my custom cell class if that helps any.

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{ self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
 CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;

        contentRect.size.height = 56.0;


        self.bannerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 56)];

        self.bannerImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        [self.contentView addSubview:bannerImageView];



    }

    return self;
}
```

Thanks for the guidance ahead of time!

Comment: If you log self.theImage.image in cellForRowAtIndexPath, does it return your image? Also, where do you have that last block of code you posted (inside what method in your cell class)? Do you know that piece of code is executed?

Comment: Your first question is a good question. I just am unsure how to log an image. Here's how I am logging it, is this the correct way to ? NSLog(@"Here's the image %@", self.imageView.image); Your second question I am not understanding.

Comment: Yes, the log is correct. What result does it give? In the second question I'm asking for more context -- where do you have that code? It has to be inside some method. What method is that?

Comment: How have you created the cell?

Comment: This solution **worked** for me..!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38973954/4034301

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the imageView background color (say to green) to see if you have a layout problem or an image loading problem.

Comment: Ahh great idea! So the background color of the image view does not change when I tell it to go green. What's the proper protocol for adding an image view programmatically to a tableview xib file? To clarify, not using a storyboard.

Comment: Figured it out! (I'll be happy to answer my own question here in a second. But the last thing I need to figure out how to place the image view in the very first cell instead of the second. Like so: `Cell 1 contains background color + image.` instead of `cell 1 contains background color` and `cell 2 contains imagee`

Answer (score 0):

if `self.theImage.image` is coming back null, try and see if `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:photoPath];` is returning something, and if it is returning something, try changing `[self.theImage setImage:image];` to `self.theImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:photoPath];`

Comment: Appreciate the reply. I think you are on to something. Weird situation. When I log `UIImage [imageWithContentsOfFile:photoPath];` it retuns an image. But when I do your method you suggested: `self.myImageViewName.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:photoPath];` And then print the image view, I get a null log message.

Comment: Hmm, that is quite strange. If the ImageView itself is null, perhaps you might want to try the initWithImage: method of the UIImageView. According to Apple docs this method: "Returns an image view initialized with the specified image."  Check this post out, I think it will lead you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497311/uiimageview-only-displays-when-i-call-initwithimage

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out my problem. So I appreciate all the suggestions of logging the photos, that really helped me. So first I create a UIImage method that returns a image. I then called that method, and set the cell.bannerImageView directly like so:

```
[cell.bannerImageView setImage:[TableViewController banner]];
```

I then had to add that image to the cell view like so:

```
 [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.bannerImageView];
```

Hope this is helpful for everyone else!

Comment: Wrong way to do it. We can help you better.